# Find Duplicate Records ID from Entity by predicate CoreData iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, predicate

How to fetch duplicate records with their ID from entity with coredata iOS Swift. I was using below but not getting correct result. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
func fetchDuplicateRecords() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EmployeeData")
    
    let nameExpr = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "name")
    
    let countExpr = NSExpressionDescription()
    let countVariableExpr = NSExpression(forVariable: "Id")
    
    countExpr.name = "count"
    countExpr.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "count:", arguments: [ nameExpr, nameExpr1, nameExpr2 ])
    countExpr.expressionResultType = .integer64AttributeType
    do {
        fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
        let idDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "Id", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [idDescriptor]
        
        fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["name"]
        fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["name", countExpr]
        fetchRequest.havingPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%ld > 1", countVariableExpr)
        
        //let results = try managedContext.execute(fetchRequest) as AnyObject
        let searchResults = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        let resultsDict = searchResults as! [[String: Int32]]
        print("\(resultsDict)")
    } catch {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 let countVariableExpr = NSExpression(forVariable: "Id")
```

should be for *count*:

```
let countVariableExpr = NSExpression(forVariable: "count")
```

and than the predicate will compare where count > 1

```
NSPredicate(format: "%@ > 1", countVariableExpr)
```

Edit:
You are currently looking for duplicate records by their name, if you want by id it would be something like this:

```
let nameExpr = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "name")
```

needs to be changed to:

```
let idExpression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "Id")
```

and then the count expression will be changed to count record ids.

```
NSExpression(forFunction: "count:", arguments: [idExpression])
```

Edit 2:

```
fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["name"]
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["name", countExpr]
```

should also be changed to fetch *Id* not *name*,

```
fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["Id"]
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["Id", countExpr]
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I tried this way also but not getting id in searchResults.

Comment: I edited my answer, check if it's working for you now.